# find the max value based on criteria in different column

Tags: excel

I need a little help in excel:

in the attached image, if I want to choose the max value of the cells in column M for every time the sum of the values in column G would be 12, is it possible?

For example: the sum of `G2+G3+G4+G5` = 12  so I need formula that will choose the max value between `M2,M3,M4,M5` (13) and then go to the next sum of cells in column `G` that would be `12`.

[image]

Comment: Hi
How did you get you columns to mirror that way?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Place this formula in cell F2 (assuming your data starts in row 2) `=IF(MOD(SUM(G$2:G2),12)=0, MAX(INDIRECT("M"&MAX(IF(F1:F$2<>"",ROW(F1:F$2),1))+1) :M2), "")`
2. Then drag down as far as you need